# netBean adding panel from other class to jframe

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe, jpanel

I just start learning java using netbean. I am now have one jFrame containing a jPanel1, and one jPanel2 class.
I want to add jPanel2 into jPanel1 in jFrame in certain  condition. So i've tried

```
if(split){
                jPanel2 = new jPanel2();
                jPanel1.add(jPanel2);
                Panel1.setVisible(true);
            }
```

I have searched over the internet and found out sort of methods to do this is using GridLayout,CardLayout or something . But i still can not do it like those tutorial even i did the same thing.Thanks so much , please don't mind for asking stupid question.

Comment: Call `jPanel1.revalidate()` followed by `jPane1.repaint()` to trigger a layout and paint pass after you've added `jPanel2` to `jPanel1`